# How to validate Size in Product details page in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

when i click on add to cart button then no error show without size selection, I want to add some validation on size if customers does not click on size then error will be shown.

[image: size validation issue in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4]

Comment: what is your product Type ?

Comment: configurable product

Comment: did you checked value required for attribute

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: can you please check with other attribute as well like color & other & if possible share screen shot with inspect element as well

Comment: here is the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/oZ0WhKc.png

Answer (score 2):

Go To Catalog => Manage Attribute => Search for Attribute `"size"`  & Values Required change from `No to Yes`